# Roller or Steamroller Effect on Soft Object such as Cookie Dough or Asphalt

Tags: soft-body

I am trying to animate a simple 2D object with a approximately 20 vertices so that it looks like it's material being rolled out such as cookie dough or asphalt being rolled over by a steamroller. I have tried Simple Deforms, Collision to a Soft Body and a Lattice Deform but can't seem to get this right. Any ideas?  Many Thanks

Comment: It's not immediately clear what 'rolling out' a 2D object means.. Could you illustrate with a sketch or reference, please?